# Align text to the top of a title

Tags: css

I'd like to align a text to the top of a title like `<h4>2004th</h4>`..

My code that doesn't work :

```css
.chronicle {
  top: 0;
}
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adilorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate reiciendis, deserunt velit veniam quidem itaque dolore dolorum, culpa aliquam similique neque voluptatibus. Porro vitae soluta cupiditate
  officia sunt, ipsa aliquam! pisicing elit. Officiis quis, architecto praesentium. Repellat voluptatibus sint tenetur illum quos cumque dicta omnis quis impedit dolores, sit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.
</div>
```

Comment: first of all, your approach needs a slighter modification. But still, if you want to go ahead with this, then add, `vertical-align:top;display:inline;` to `.chronicle` class. It takes the Lorem Ipsum on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` and `float:left` to the title

```css
.chronicle {
  top: 0;
}
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adilorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate reiciendis, deserunt velit veniam quidem itaque dolore dolorum, culpa aliquam similique neque voluptatibus. Porro vitae soluta cupiditate
  officia sunt, ipsa aliquam! pisicing elit. Officiis quis, architecto praesentium. Repellat voluptatibus sint tenetur illum quos cumque dicta omnis quis impedit dolores, sit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if I get you right, use `vertical-align:top` for align your `inline-block`.

```css
.chronicle {
  top: 0;
}
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adilorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate reiciendis, deserunt velit veniam quidem itaque dolore dolorum, culpa aliquam similique neque voluptatibus. Porro vitae soluta cupiditate
  officia sunt, ipsa aliquam! pisicing elit. Officiis quis, architecto praesentium. Repellat voluptatibus sint tenetur illum quos cumque dicta omnis quis impedit dolores, sit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.
</div>
```

Or if you mean align all text like `sup` to top for your `h1`, you need to use that

```css
.chronicle {
  top: 0;
}
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

sup {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003 <sup> Lorem ipsum dolsit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.</sup></h1>
</div>
```

Or if you want your `h1` not float text, you need to remove `display: inline-block` from it.

The question is very unclear :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you just want to use `<sup>test</sup>`. You can also style it if you want special design.

```html
<div class="chronicles"><sup>2000th</sup> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Comment: If I replace the titles by `sup` it doesn't work on my snippet... `sup` is not align to the top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.chronicle {
  top: 0;
}
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.title-text{
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003</h1>
 <span class="title-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adilorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate reiciendis, deserunt velit veniam quidem itaque dolore dolorum, culpa aliquam similique neque voluptatibus. Porro vitae soluta cupiditate
  officia sunt, ipsa aliquam! pisicing elit. Officiis quis, architecto praesentium. Repellat voluptatibus sint tenetur illum quos cumque dicta omnis quis impedit dolores, sit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same like this:

```css
.chronicle h5,
.chronicle h4,
.chronicle h3,
.chronicle h2,
.chronicle h1 {
  margin: 0 0px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.chronicle > h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.chronicle > span {
 font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chronicle">
  <h1>2003</h1><span>th</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adilorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate reiciendis, deserunt velit veniam quidem itaque dolore dolorum, culpa aliquam similique neque voluptatibus. Porro vitae soluta cupiditate
  officia sunt, ipsa aliquam! pisicing elit. Officiis quis, architecto praesentium. Repellat voluptatibus sint tenetur illum quos cumque dicta omnis quis impedit dolores, sit est placeat maxime. Est, earum.</p>
</div>
```